# PostgreSQL count(distinct(varchar)) and over (partition) not working as in other databases

Tags: postgresql

I have following table which should be updated based on two columns within the same table. In SQL SEVER for such calculations I used to use Over(partition by ) but it is not working in PostgreSQL. How to achieve the following in PostgreSQL

Table name assesment, and table structure is given below:. 
If Current_status and targert_staus for all sub_cap are closed, status for capacity,cap_status will be complete. if any value in current_status or target_status is open for a Capacity then cap_status will be open. Same applies for Function, if all Capacity are closed then Func_staus is Complete else Open. Same applies for Site.

```
Id  Site    Function    Capacity    sub_cap current_status      target_status   site_status func_status cap_status
C1  S1  F1      C1      SC1     Close           Close   
C2  S1  F1      C1      SC2     Close           Close               
C3  S1  F1      C2      SC7     Close           Close
C4  S2  F1      C1      SC3     Close           Close
C5  S2  F1      C1      SC4     Close           Close
C6  S2  F1      C2      SC5     Close           Open
C7  S2  F1      C3      SC6     Open            Close
C8  S2  F1      C4      SC6     Open            Open
```

Under each site if all sub_cap have closed status are ‘closed’ then Site_STATUS column should be ‘COMPLETE’
Under each Function if all sub_cap have closed status are ‘closed’ then Func_STATUS column should be ‘COMPLETE’
Under each Capacity if all sub_cap have closed status are ‘closed’ then Cap_STATUS column should be ‘COMPLETE’

```
Id  Site    Function    Capacity    sub_cap current_status      target_status   site_status func_status cap_status
C1  S1  F1      C1      SC1     Close           Close       COMPLETE    COMPLETE    COMPLETE
C2  S1  F1      C1      SC2     Close           Close       COMPLETE    COMPLETE    COMPLETE        
C3  S1  F2      C2      SC7     Close           Close       COMPLETE    COMPLETE    COMPLETE
C4  S2  F1      C1      SC3     Close           Close       OPEN        OPEN        COMPLETE
C5  S2  F1      C1      SC4     Close           Close       OPEN        OPEN        COMPLETE
C6  S2  F1      C2      SC5     Close           Open        OPEN        OPEN        OPEN
C7  S2  F3      C3      SC6     Open            Close       OPEN        OPEN        OPEN
C8  S2  F4      C4      SC6     Open            Open        OPEN        OPEN        OPEN
```

Comment: Postgres does not support `distinct` in window functions (and neither does SQL Server if I'm not mistaken). Also: `distinct` isn't a a function. `distinct (a)` is exactly the same thing as `distinct a`

Comment: Your posted results do not flow from your requirement description.  "Current_status and targert_staus for all sub_cap are closed, status for capacity,cap_status will be complete" and goes on to say if any are open then status is  open. Yet your results for cap_status contains mixed values. If result bases on **all** current and target values then the it should contain a distinct value. What is the other determinant Site/Function/Capacity other? Thanks for posting data as text but use [formatted text](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) in the future, difference being column alignment